# Entry to schengen countries

Tags: schengen, norway, 90-180-visa-rules

I need help on counting days. If I will visit Norway 28.11-30.11 (counting like 3 days right?), I don't need visa but have 90 days within 180 to stay in schengen zone. 
After that I want to entry again in 3.3.18 I will have 87 days but I need a little more so I want to go out in 26.5 for 2 days and then the 180 days counting will be reset. After that I have another 90 days to be in Norway? Does it work like that? The dates is not 100% accurate but you get the idea.
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

According to your description, you will be *outside* the Schengen zone for all of December, January and February, which is 90 days in total.

After you have been outside Schengen for 90 contiguous days, it is impossible for any *previous* visits to restrict further stays under the 90/180 rule: Since every 180-day period that contains both your November visit and dates in March or later will contain those 90 days outside, you can't possibly be inside the Schengen area for more than 90 days out of such a period.

**However,** notice that **there is no such thing as "the 180 days counting will be reset"**.

If you enter on March 3 and leave on May 26, that visit will have taken 85 days. You then only have 5 days of presence in the Schengen area left for the 180-day period that starts on March 3 and ends August 29. You can distribute those 5 days however you want, but there is no way to "reset the count" and get more days, except by waiting long enough that March 3 is farther than 180 days in the past.

Comment: No way to reset the count with the exception of applying for a long term visa for/residency of a Schengen country.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk that still doesn't reset the count.  It just lets you stay in the country issuing the visa without being subject to the rule.  The rule still applies for the rest of the Schengen zone, however, though the chances of being held to it are probably very slim.